# Does being a jack-of-all-trades hurt your career?

Tags: career-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to specialize in a single field I like, or expand into other fields to broaden my horizons?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20653/is-it-better-to-specialize-in-a-single-field-i-like-or-expand-into-other-fields)

Looking at job postings, the vast majority ask for extremely specific qualifications and requirements and a great deal of experience in very narrow areas.

Having written a job description or two myself, I know that the "requirements" are more of a wish-list than anything, and actual job duties can vary wildly.

That said, if I look at these job postings as a potential applicant, I don't think I'd even be considered for most of them - mainly because I don't really have a specialty or area of strong focus.

I can do just about anything marginally well (programming, database, networking, you name it), and have had experience with a wide range of different technologies (at varying levels of expertise), but I've never had a job that required or otherwise had a need to drill deep down into something, spend a lot of time on it, and "master" it.

Does being a jack-of-all trades really hurt your career (long term)?

Does that mean that you will never be able to move up or advance beyond something like Tier 1/2 tech support or general IT-lackey?

In the same vein, is it possible to make a career out of being versatile with technology, having a wide range of (albeit shallow) experience, but without specializing in a particular technology?